# Load mapbox.js from typescript as module under Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, npm, angular, mapbox

How to load mapbox.js nmp module in the Component written on typescript for Angular 2 under Visual Studio 2015?

I did try a lot options but no one get mapbox.js loaded. In case of questions I can provide more details.